# Convert motif .uil files to QT .ui files

Tags: qt, motif

Anybody knows of a tool to convert motif .uil files to QT .ui files?
Or a script like converting the .uil to xml and then to .ui files. 
I have a lot of .uil files so defintely not doing that manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Qt Motif Extension](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/docs/qt3/motif-walkthrough.html). This has been dropped since Qt4, however, but it may still work to help you convert your `motif` files.